# How can I take input without spaces in array?

Tags: c++

I made this class with an array in it. I need to handle reading a 45 digit integer. I made an `>>` operator like this:

```cpp
istream& operator>>(istream &input, MyInt &s){
    in >> s.v[0] >> s.v[1] >> s.v[2] >> s.v[3] >> s.v[4];
    return input;
}
```

Now, if I read in a number like this in `main()`:

```cpp
MyInt number;
cin >> number;
```

I have to write the number like this

> 111111111 111111111 111111111 111111111 111111111

How can I take the input as this instead?

> 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Comment: Read as a single long string? Then split up the string any way you like.

Comment: And then you will have to parse the string into separate variables

Answer (score 2):

The [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) function is what you're looking for. Then you can consume a specific amount of the input number. You'll have to convert the strings to `int`s your self, I'd suggest using [`stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

However, I'd suggest reading into a string first so you can know how long the input was and then using [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to separate it into parts.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try It.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define MAX_INPUT_LENGTH     100

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char input[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];
    char convert[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];
    char undesirePattern = ' ';
    cout << "please Enter Your Number:\n";
    cin.getline(input, MAX_INPUT_LENGTH);
    for (size_t count = 0; count < MAX_INPUT_LENGTH; count++)
    {
        static size_t innerCount = 0;
        if (input[count] != undesirePattern)
        {
            convert[innerCount] = input[count];
            innerCount++;
        }
    }
    std::string numberStr = convert;
    long long numberInt = stoi(numberStr);
    cout << numberInt << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This how you can take input without space in array in c++**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[5][4];
    string str;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> str ;        //take input as string
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = str[j];       //put string character in 2-d array one-by-one
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
             cout << a[i][j] << " ";         //print array with space
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
 return 0;
}
```

**Input**  (without space)
10001
00000
11111
10101
10001

**Output**
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1